# I can't remove default routing during a boot of Linux

Tags: networking, routes, embedded-linux

I setup network through systemd.network service. I have two interfaces. eth0(wire) and wwan0(wireless). I described it in two files:

20-wire.network

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=192.168.100.1/24
#Gateway=192.168.2.16
DefaultRouteOnDevice=false
[Route]
Gateway=192.168.2.16
```

25-wireless.network

```
[Match]
Name=wwan0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
DNS=8.8.8.8
DefaultRouteOnDevice=true
```

I would want my default routing always was through wwan0.
But after booting or creating ssh-session occurs added default routing through eth0.

```
unnecessary route-->default dev eth0 scope link
default via 192.168.2.16 dev wwan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.2.136 metric 1024 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 169.254.73.67 
192.168.2.0/24 dev wwan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.136 
192.168.2.16 dev wwan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.2.136 metric 1024 
192.168.100.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.1
```

Comment: Look at NetworkManager, nmtui or nmcli are interfaces for it

Comment: @geckos ,Thanks! I looked at connman setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Networkmanager - connman set up default routing. I disabled it in the /var/lib/connman/ethernet_00049f05e066_cable/settings. I changed the parameter:

> AutoConnect=true on false